# Alternative example for capscale function in vegan package

Tags: r, statistics, vegan, multivariate-testing

I have been learning multivariate analyses in PRIMER, yet now want to convert to R using the `vegan` package. I wish to use the `capscale()` function in `vegan`, yet am not sure how my data should be formatted beforehand. 
In the example in the vignette http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/capscale.html, both `dataframes` (`varespec` and `varechem`) have numeric values only, yet I have one `dataframe` of dependent (numeric) values, and another of independent (factor) values. So what I am asking for is an alternative worked example that I might be able to emulate. I can't find anything online.
The `iris` data set should provide sufficient toy data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vignette source you use is badly outdated: I got to remove it from the Web. The help page for `?capscale` should contain more up-to-date documentation in your current **vegan** installation. For the independent data with factors, you should be able to use the model of any other constrained ordination help (`?rda`) which tell you that with `formula` interface you can have factors in the independent data -- and the `formula` interface is the only allowed interface in `capscale`.

You should switch from `capscale` to `dbrda` in **vegan**: `capscale` may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Hi Jari, sorry but I absolutely cannot get this to work. Can you please indicate how you would go about entering the formula with the `iris` dataset? I am trying things like `capscale(iris[1:4]~iris$species,data=iris)`
Thank you very much

Comment: `capscale(iris[,1:4] ~ Species, data=iris)` seems to work. NB, the indexing of *columns*  with `[, 1:4]` and uppercase first letter in `Species`.

Comment: Using your example returns this for me: `capscale(iris[,1:4] ~ Species, data=iris)
Call: 
capscale(formula = iris[, 1:4] ~ Species, data = iris)

Regularization parameters: 
NULL

Prior probabilities of groups: 
NULL

Misclassification rate: 
       apparent:  %
Warning message:
In is.na(x$error.rate[1]) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'`

Comment: you must be using something else than `vegan::capscale()`: It just does not have "Regularization paremeres", "Prior probabilities" or such. What is the software you were using?

Comment: Wow! What a lot of frustration for nothing. I loaded the vegan package alone and it worked. Thank you so much for helping me figure this out!