# how to use capscale {vegan} r

Tags: r, vegan

I have used

```
?capscale
```

and scoured the internet for answers, but am still not understanding what should be the dependent variable for my dataset if I want to use

```
capscale()
```

to analyze my data.

I have NDVI data with some continuous and some categorical variables:

```
ndvi=structure(list(siteOID = 25840:25939, Elevation = c(1871.92, 
1875.38, 1878.28, 1878.54, 1878.33, 1879.2, 1880.51, 1883.78, 
1884.6, 1884.85, 1885.46, 1888.72, 1890.94, 1897.19, 1901.95, 
1902.47, 1902.81, 1903.49, 1906.62, 1908.73, 1909.4, 1910.65, 
1913.44, 1915, 1915.81, 1918.06, 1920.01, 1921.53, 1925.48, 1926.66, 
1927.64, 1931.02, 1932.8, 1935.27, 1938.33, 1941.19, 1945.71, 
1948.68, 1951.52, 1951.83, 1955.76, 1961.02, 1963.92, 1963.25, 
1969.53, 1972.56, 1977.92, 1978.93, 1981.54, 1985.64, 1987.6, 
1987.62, 1988.78, 1991.92, 1997.03, 1998.06, 1998.98, 2001.26, 
2006.97, 2009.56, 2009.81, 2011.55, 2017.92, 2021.75, 2023.42, 
2024.91, 2028.15, 2032.83, 2032.83, 2033.5, 2035.75, 2037.44, 
2045.51, 2047.38, 2049.85, 2052.33, 2059.36, 2069.27, 2071.41, 
2071.83, 2074.15, 2081.55, 2083.52, 2086.3, 2090.5, 2095.57, 
2096.69, 2100.65, 2108.06, 2110.48, 2113.45, 2121.78, 2124.82, 
2133.54, 2137.54, 2146.43, 2150.53, 2156.63, 2160.05, 2168.57
), Shape_Area = c(2940.395887, 5105.447128, 3763.362181, 2801.775054, 
3854.690283, 4627.01632, 6863.6264, 5452.724569, 3504.284818, 
3967.710707, 7004.963815, 3926.00215, 7645.532158, 6306.085153, 
3451.101972, 4699.688114, 3880.378241, 4792.898829, 5542.142348, 
3674.957345, 3562.897792, 3219.790167, 5369.915585, 3854.684578, 
3737.522732, 5190.103216, 5137.457907, 4753.975071, 3605.727759, 
4682.430962, 3412.007599, 4955.96479, 0, 5106.057222, 3026.454348, 
6814.973732, 5422.439336, 4523.077568, 3092.711952, 2667.1801, 
2318.487235, 1623.008863, 2672.648264, 2524.245809, 2164.660806, 
3153.921959, 3170.875701, 3755.980623, 4505.277, 3954.724973, 
3592.717424, 2877.927426, 3465.37684, 2317.185185, 3249.657309, 
2710.26402, 3421.803771, 2556.020604, 3849.407062, 3782.797907, 
1950.365079, 3522.797668, 2340.599897, 2451.029503, 3034.109721, 
2873.167998, 2278.337947, 2546.02206, 3545.854694, 3514.69201, 
2731.819076, 2537.618027, 2116.84627, 2213.553587, 4430.489625, 
2648.387315, 4408.844477, 3453.225099, 2457.844425, 3597.718985, 
3933.191433, 3280.424579, 2309.053402, 4062.750209, 2755.087578, 
3785.974581, 3485.221528, 4698.642524, 3647.400111, 4512.594002, 
4509.418612, 3908.621289, 5856.573472, 4084.254238, 4772.464487, 
4587.251362, 3275.527576, 3236.108516, 4771.636048, 5241.064376
),slopemean = c(7.012740221, 6.374673005, 6.713881453, 6.219425964, 
5.393005565, 5.567550724, 4.557037692, 5.122994391, 5.608577084, 
5.054081163, 3.020378928, 3.535192937, 2.910682318, 2.262314184, 
1.872473637, 2.04489899, 1.358906129, 1.738190173, 2.190473907, 
2.285263883, 1.932403531, 1.318049102, 2.323188104, 2.838744229, 
2.5508166, 3.662199524, 2.645026659, 2.691092801, 2.209619006, 
2.360828268, 2.83633309, 2.917255029, 3.814524024, 3.594417877, 
2.537033654, 2.758014447, 6.487904879, 6.546860137, 6.611400228, 
6.548973659, 7.320545057, 7.167488849, 7.486095047, 6.736548642, 
6.978404939, 6.209158245, 5.780635711, 5.952286865, 6.21757545, 
6.026404989, 8.286706911, 5.013909823, 4.302618208, 5.958519395, 
4.735497169, 6.86024694, 5.923437148, 4.814125561, 6.278868822, 
6.369820399, 4.211901608, 5.067338774, 7.276210246, 9.342363631, 
7.382804547, 7.026542905, 7.386944243, 6.993269548, 4.999933584, 
5.386859906, 5.74222567, 6.407413812, 6.220262604, 6.361011563, 
7.89187751, 7.504486516, 8.071826326, 7.282463079, 5.730589071, 
6.75588336, 5.865557512, 5.567460529, 5.743696501, 6.234486916, 
6.672290961, 4.424730467, 3.993647329, 5.934593258, 7.937450668, 
8.264807165, 7.39251924, 7.862093222, 6.829388913, 7.447980573, 
6.477102849, 6.185640762, 7.760704698, 8.44009344, 8.557933442, 
7.60872553), avwidth = c(41.38533, 44.11806, 43.54585, 38.07962, 
40.80878, 49.52246, 49.97194, 51.36124, 50.45419, 51.12577, 52.46919, 
49.68379, 43.48322, 51.95128, 46.91944, 58.70265, 55.41018, 50.92463, 
55.55058, 45.73485, 50.29035, 49.08618, 52.57013, 51.48199, 52.90921, 
44.27491, 55.71036, 50.08104, 47.3439, 49.8397, 51.81409, 50.43767, 
60.95491, 38.50229, 47.8118, 52.66532, 44.10194, 46.67934, 46.46481, 
37.64217, 21.84973, 25.04575, 33.79403, 29.61029, 29.71018, 21.3549, 
28.02716, 38.25882, 45.25996, 40.10562, 46.15768, 40.82856, 42.1975, 
31.75748, 32.83316, 34.33412, 33.54285, 39.29999, 33.25312, 33.65804, 
30.00087, 32.63515, 31.11767, 31.14068, 27.83876, 30.20586, 34.80735, 
32.65111, 38.31069, 43.65983, 35.21719, 32.87317, 28.83573, 33.8517, 
29.72621, 32.61762, 31.11199, 23.89315, 31.26606, 33.78306, 34.89358, 
38.64512, 34.68206, 34.2003, 44.12035, 35.59922, 48.34063, 47.52268, 
47.02729, 51.07513, 51.5254, 43.25953, 47.01821, 38.28714, 35.90366, 
40.30569, 48.04857, 54.46596, 49.70541, 49.18992), watershed = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("marys", "reese", "wwalker"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, siteOID is each individual site and the categorical variable is watershed.

Now, I am trying to evaluate potential influences of NDVI in multivariate space, by conducting a Canonical Analysis of Principal Coordinates on a Gower similarity matrix of scaled habitat variables using the “capscale” function from the vegan package in R (Oksanen et al. 2013).

```
ndvi.cap <- capscale(siteOID~ Elevation + Shape_Area + avwidth + slopemean + watershed, ndvi,
                     dist="bray")
```

I don't understand how capscale formula is meant to be set up due to the lack of examples with actual explanations of what should be the dependent variable. The example in

```
?capscale

## Basic Analysis
vare.cap <- capscale(varespec ~ N + P + K + Condition(Al), varechem,
                     dist="bray")
vare.cap
plot(vare.cap)
anova(vare.cap)
```

uses two (!) different datasets, which does not make sense to me. Should I be putting the actual NDVI values as the dependent variable and not the site? I do have many NDVI-related variables associated with each site (actual NDVI value, differences between seasons, sens slope for trend), but I am not sure if a continuous variable should be listed as the dependent variable or not.

My question is similar to : [Alternative example for capscale function in vegan package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061666/alternative-example-for-capscale-function-in-vegan-package)

but the answer given there did not help me.

Comment: This sounds like more that you don't understand what capscale does; it's a *multivariate* method where the response is typically a whole data frame or matrix of multiple response variables (think counts of m species at each of n sites) that we wish to model using one or more covariates (in another data frame / matrix). The main difference between capscale and other related methods is that you can analyse any dissimilarity matrix computed from the multivariate response.

Comment: If you're just looking to model a single variable (and I see no point in modelling the site ID) then you'll likely be better off with a univariate regression (try `glm()` or `mgcv::gam()` for starters).